# printing CSV in a different way

Tags: python, csv

I need to print out a rankinglist from a csv file. I can get it printed out, that's not the problem but it will look like this:

```
[['team1', '100'], ['team2', '200'], ['team3', '300']]
```

I want it to print out like this:

```
team1, 100
team2, 200
team3, 300
```

I found that my knowledge of Python/ english language isn't high enough to understand what is being explained on other stackoverflow topics here so I have to ask you to be as simple as possible
this is the piece of code that I'm using

```
def read():
    a = open('casus.csv','r')
    Areader = csv.reader(a)
    a = []
    for row in Areader:
        if len (row) != 0:
            a = a + [row]
    print(a)
```

Comment: keep in mind you want to print info from _every_ row, but your loop doesn't print info from every row. try printing info inside your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have exactly two elements in each list, this should work.

```
def read():
    a = open('casus.csv','r')
    Areader = csv.reader(a)
    for row in Areader:
        if len(row != 0):
            print(row[0]+","+row[1])
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/d6qk6x)  This a screenshot of what I'm using ( left- csv file, middle- error and right - code)

Comment: have you got any idea?

Comment: my bad! what i meant was this actually

Comment: def read():
    a = open('casus.csv','r')
    Areader = csv.reader(a)
    for row in Areader:
        if len(row) != 0:
            print(row[0]+","+row[1])

Comment: the problem with the misplaced closing bracket,

Comment: Well maybe one more thing but that's luxury, can I order them on the score column? High to low

Comment: of course you can, but it would need an extra book keeping, you would need to keep the values you read from the csv file in a list and then convert the numbers that were read as strings to actual numbers by using the int()  method, then you would need to change the order in which they appear in the list like [number,String] which would allow us to order them in ascending or descending order, then reverse them back. do you still think you wanna do it?

Comment: Well i need to produce a ranking list it says nothing about order, but that's something to be assumed i guess. So yes i still want to do it

Comment: sorry, connections. i'll get back to you with the some code really soon!

Comment: here is an a link to the image, replace the MyCsv.csv file name to your file name. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgUEZodEgzaDRJc0U/view)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your piece of code but I got this error: [link](http://prntscr.com/d6vh1i)

Comment: well, i had tried it before sending you the code and it worked. u get that kind of error if you used only one value at one of your rows. i'll send you the link to the output image and the csv file i used

Comment: here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgNGRfSDkxcWt5WTQ/view?usp=sharing) make sure the data you stored in your csv file looks like the one in the image.hope it works,

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/d6w52i) im pretty sure i copied it exactly and here is my csv [link](http://prntscr.com/d6w59z)

Comment: well that's sad to hear, i just run it using the data u sent and it worked, i think it would be better if i have a look over your code just to check for some bugs. here is the link to the result i obtained [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgdVZMMnBSY1ZnZEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: and what is that vraag function you are calling? make sure you are calling read()

Comment: upload it to your google drive and then share the link

Comment: I'm getting " list index out of range" for every line in the function containing "row[0]" or "row [1]"

Comment: try sending the code for now, i will try to figure out what went wrong with your code, cause it's working fine for me

Comment: I sent it in previous comment

Comment: fixed it, you had a row in your csv file that had 3 values separated in commas, and again adding the if len(row) != 0 helped solve the problem. here is the link to your files [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgOTI3NkJBWjFLRm8/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgY0dhWnUyLTduU2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: yes you can, and i'm gonna add a little bit something to achieve that, 5 minutes..

Comment: Do your thing man I'll be around for a couple of more hours, you may even add stuff that would make it better in your opinion. I will get a grade for this! I'm gonna mention you as source.

Comment: that would be an honor, this is actually my first time helping somebody over stackoverflow, just signed up, anyways did my thing and here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3P1g9X1PJTgZ20zeUxzQk9qeVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well you did a tremendous job in helping me! Thank you very much! You'd make a fine teacher on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but you can easily just iterate over the list:

```
for team in a:
    print("{}, {}".format(team[0], team[1]))
```

Just add it after you made the list. Although a better way would be to either print it as you read it or use a dictionary.